# Ionic grid 2 columns where left column in fixed and right column is scrollable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm having trouble finding any documentation on how exactly this works. In it's simplest form I want to get the code below to have the left column be stationary (or possibly also scroll independently) and the right column to scroll. This is an Ionic 4 / Angular 11 app.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="6">
    
This column does not scroll
    
    </ion-col>
     <ion-col size="6">
  
This column does scroll when it exceeds screen height
     
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-3yiyi7?
In a nutshell, it's all in the css: play with `overflow-y` property and add see if you'd want scrollbar to show or not with `display`. Also, note the difference between browsers in css.

Comment: That appear to be working. Is there a way to set the height in the CSS to the height (variable) of the screen it is being displayed on?

Comment: You could try with `height: 100vh` where `vh` stands for viewport height, or experiment with `vmin` (viewport minimum length) and `vmax` (viewport maximum length).